How can I regain restricted API access for my Facebook application after verifying my Meta Business Account
My API access was restricted because it wasn't linked to a verified business account. I have completed a business verification with the associated app. Now its not letting me resolve this issue even though my business verification was successful. See screenshot below
screenshot of required action in FB admin console
I have verified the business associated to the app and I expected to be able to select that business and progress to resolve the issue but the "Next" button is disabled even though the associated business is now verified
